# calling method from another class using thread ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsthread

I have two classes one is Sample class and ServerConnection class.

sample.m

```
.
.
    ServerConnection *serverConnection = [[ServerConnection alloc]init:val1 _handler:serverConnectionHandler _connectionURL:url];
//    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(run) toTarget:serverConnection withObject:NULL];    
    [serverConnection performSelectorInBackground:@selector(run) withObject:NULL];
```

In serverConnection i have only two methods
ServerConnection.h

```
@interface ServerConnection : NSObject
{
//    NSString* url;
//    Handler* handler;
//    int action_code;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* url;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Handler* handler;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber* action_code;

-(id) init:(int)_action_code _handler:(Handler *)_handler _connectionURL:(NSString *)_connectionURL;
-(void)run;
```

ServerConnection.m

```
- (id) init:(int)_action_code _handler:(Handler *)_handler _connectionURL:(NSString *)_connectionURL{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        action_code = 0;
        action_code = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:_action_code];
        handler = [[Handler alloc]init:_handler];
        url = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:_connectionURL];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)run
{
     NSLog(@"url--> %@",url);

   //Here using NSURLConnection to fetch data from server
}
```

when run methods starts i'll get this error sometimes **Excess bad access** and after enabling zombie showing this error message
 -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xf9978d0*
and 
 ****malloc:**  error for object 0x11039420: pointer being freed was not allocated
 **set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug****

i referred old posts and tried to solve but still facing the same issue. anyone please point me where i am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong here with your `url` ivar. Is this your whole code? What's the `ServerConnection` lifecycle? Monday morning can be the reason that I don't see anything suspicious ... Few additional comments ...

`action_code = 0;` line is useless, because you're assigning `NSNumber` on the next line. And `action_code` is `NSNumber`, so, even if you want to assign 0 to it, you should write `action_code = @( 0 )`.

Also the style ... `action_code` should be named as `actionCode`. The `init...` method should look like:

```
- (id)initWithActionCode:(int)actionCode handler:(Handler *)handler connectionURL:(NSString *) connectionURL {
```

And `if (self = [super init]) {` should look like `if ( ( self = [super init] ) ) {` or use two liner:

```
self = [super init];
if ( self ) {
```

You should improve your style to make your code more readable by others.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestions. i'll change my code as you suggested.serverConnection run method'll be called when ever i want to fetch data from server using Url, so i can access this from other class also